# Shooting vertical (sideways) from a mount: camera tilts down

Tags: shooting-technique

I need to shoot in vertical format. The camera (Sony NEX-5RK) is clamped to a vertical round stand with a grip-like mount. My problem: no matter how hard I tighten the 1/4" camera screw on the mount, the weight of the lens slowly tilts the camera down (i.e. the camera rotates around the 1/4" screw). Neither the camera nor the mount have any additional pegs/holes that would keep the camera in place. I ended up tying the lens to the mount with a piece of insulated wire. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be to use tripod, not stand. This will give you much more stability and solution to set your camera on different positions.

And to use also [L bracket](https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/Quick-Release-Vertical-L-Plate-Bracket-for-Sony-Nex5-Nex5n-Arca-SUNWAYFOTO-Fit/1649171985) to mount the camera to the tripod vertically and keep the center of gravity over the tripod head/mount.

Also depend of the lens you use (if it's long heavy lens) you can consider mount the lens to the tripod (or eventually stand) to keep even more precise the center of gravity over the mount point.

To see what I am talk about check [this page](https://shuttermuse.com/ultimate-guide-to-camera-l-plates/), second photo

P.S. I have no affiliate with any of the products or sellers

Comment: Thanks I'm in the US, I found the link below. Looking at the L-bracket, I'm still not sure: what on the bracket forces the camera to keep its position? https://www.ebay.com/itm/USA-Quick-Release-Vertical-L-Plate-Bracket-For-Sony-NEX5-NEX5N-Arca-Swiss-Fit/263847334295?hash=item3d6e86d197:g:k-oAAOSwrnNXP1WJ:rk:2:pf:0

Comment: @MrSparkly, IMHO this is what you need. But this will help (a lot) in case of tripod. Not sure about stand.... And the idea is to turn camera vertically and mount the short mount on tripod

Comment: @MrSparkly, check my edited answer

Comment: @MrSparkly _what on the bracket forces the camera to keep its position?_ Friction, mostly. Being able to secure the bracket *tightly* with the hex key provides a lot of the resistance to twisting force. Unfortunately, the base of your Sony is quite small, so it doesn't provide a lot of surface area to prevent twisting due to a front-heavy lens.

Comment: @Romeo Ninov Ah, thanks, now I get it. With the L-bracket, the camera ends up sitting ON TOP of the tripod, not on the SIDE of the tripod (as I was imagining it). Thanks.